# android - center a gridview on the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a an activity whose layout is made of:

- a header
- a gridview
- a footer

I want the grid to be at the center of the screen, but when i launch the app it is immediately below the header, and as it consists of few elements, the rest of the screen up to the footer is empty.
I want in a way move the grid more at the center to compensate this empty.

This is the xml of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gridrelativelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient">

    <!--  Header -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/header" >

        <!-- Logo -->
        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"/>
        <!-- /Logo -->

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- /Header -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_dashboard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="5dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--  Footer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/header" >

        <!-- Logo -->
        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/rainbow_footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
           <!-- /Logo -->


    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- /Footer -->

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/grid_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_yt"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/yout" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_fb"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fb" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_email"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/email" />

        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any advice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: read the documentation for relativelayout. everything regarding positioning items in it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

For your grid view section

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_dashboard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @SegFault It would be better if put the screenshot too

Answer (score 0):

Your linear layout needs to be the size of your screen using match_parent or fill_parent depending where it is(assuming you are placing your grid view in the middle of the screen).

Inside of this linear layout create your GridView which is going to be set to wrap_content and your layout_gravity must be set to center, not center_horizontal.